# Slick Grid: Slick grid using with Bootstrap popup calendar issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, slickgrid

I am using slick grid with Bootstrap . I have a slick grid in my page and onclik of a button of that page one Bootstrap pop up will open thenin that popup I have to choose a date to insert in that cell. My calendar is coming but in behind the popup.

What should I do.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the follwing code in your page to solve the issue
here ui-datepicker-div is a id so hash symbol need to prefix

ui-datepicker-div
{ z-index: 99999 !important; /* must be > than popup editor (950) */ }